# "An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions." What conditions?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

This is what the W3C Validator prints for an img tag without an alt attribute:

*"An img element must have an alt attribute, **except under certain conditions**."*

I can't find anything about it... at least nothing more than what the alt tag is about.

Does anybody know **what conditions**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#when-a-text-alternative-is-not-available-at-the-time-of-publication) outlines the reason:

> In some cases an image is included in a published document, but the
>   author is unable to provide an appropriate text alternative. In such
>   cases the minimum requirement is to provide a caption for the image
>   using the figure and figcaption elements under the following
>   conditions:
>
> - The img element is in a figure element
> - The figure element contains a figcaption element
> - The figcaption element contains content other than inter-element whitespace
> - Ignoring the figcaption element and its descendants, the figure element has no Text node descendants other than inter-element
>     whitespace, and no embedded content descendant other than the img
>     element.
>
> In other words, the only content of the figure is an img element and a
>   figcaption element, and the figcaption element must include (caption)
>   content.
>
> Such cases are to be kept to an absolute minimum. If there is even the
>   slightest possibility of the author having the ability to provide real
>   alternative text, then it would not be acceptable to omit the alt
>   attribute.

Code example of an allowable case for no alt attribute:

```
<figure>
<img src="clara.jpg">
<figcaption>clara.jpg, taken on 12/11/2010.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[WHATWG.org](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#guidance-for-conformance-checkers) adds:

> A conformance checker must report the lack of an alt attribute as an
>   error unless one of the conditions listed below applies:
>
> - The img element is in a figure element that satisfies the conditions described above.
> - The img element has a title attribute with a value that is not the empty string (also as described above).
> - The conformance checker has been configured to assume that the document is an e-mail or document intended for a specific person who
>     is known to be able to view images.
> - The img element has a (non-conforming) generator-unable-to-provide-required-alt attribute whose value is the
>     empty string. A conformance checker that is not reporting the lack of
>     an alt attribute as an error must also not report the presence of the
>     empty generator-unable-to-provide-required-alt attribute as an error.
>     (This case does not represent a case where the document is conforming,
>     only that the generator could not determine appropriate alternative
>     text — validators are not required to show an error in this case,
>     because such an error might encourage markup generators to include
>     bogus alternative text purely in an attempt to silence validators.
>     Naturally, conformance checkers may report the lack of an alt
>     attribute as an error even in the presence of the
>     generator-unable-to-provide-required-alt attribute; for example, there
>     could be a user option to report all conformance errors even those
>     that might be the more or less inevitable result of using a markup
>     generator.)

Comment: This seems to be the only part in the entire subsection about alt text that is enforceable by validation. Can't speak for the rest.

Comment: `The img element has a (non-conforming) generator-unable-to-provide-required-alt attribute whose value is the empty string.` :D great